# How to get the range of integers supported by Lua?

Tags: lua

I wonder if it's possible to get the minimum/maximum number in Lua.

For example, in C++ we have the following

```
std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

Is there something similar in Lua?

Comment: No there is not. And it is different depending upon how Lua was configured. It might be worth throwing this question into the mailing list to start a discussion on whether this should be added to the language or not.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  This is a good question.

Comment: If you're talking about floating point numbers, the "minimum" and "maximum" number representable aren't going to be meaningful (though there is `math.huge` which is bigger than all other floats). Only Lua 5.3 has a separate integer type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [math.min](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-math.min) and [math.max](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-math.max) that each take a list of values and return the minimum and the maximum value.

(I realized I might have misunderstood the question, as it's about integer limits, rather than comparison). There is [math.mininteger](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-math.mininteger) and [math.maxinteger](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-math.maxinteger) that return "an integer with the minimum/maximum value for an integer".

Comment: Thank you `math.mininteger` and `math.maxinteger` works like a charm.

Comment: This is all specific to Lua 5.3 though, as previous versions use double precision floating point numbers by default, and the maximum value of that is `inf`, which you can get from `math.huge` (assuming you didn't specifically compile Lua with a different number type)

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer explains, this functionality is not available out-of-the-box in standard Lua.   However, it is very easy to implement this functionality with your own Lua-C module.

**`test.cpp`**

```cpp
#include <limits>
#include <lua.hpp>

static const luaL_Reg limits_lib[] = {
    {nullptr, nullptr} // sentinel
};

LUAMOD_API int luaopen_limits(lua_State *L) {
    luaL_newlib(L, limits_lib);
    lua_pushnumber(L, std::numeric_limits<lua_Number>::max());
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "maxnumber");
    lua_pushnumber(L, std::numeric_limits<lua_Number>::min());
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "minnumber");
    return 1;
}
```

**`test.lua`**

```lua
local limits = require("limits")
print(limits.maxnumber)
print(limits.minnumber)
```

Example invocation:

```
$ clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -I /usr/include/lua5.2 -shared -fPIC test.cpp -o limits.so -llua5.2
$ lua5.2 test.lua
1.7976931348623e+308
2.2250738585072e-308
```

Answer (score 1):

Before Lua 5.3 all numbers were double by default and so can represent integers up to 2^52.