# Use string.format to convert a string value to a long number and meet a strange issue

Tags: lua

Lua version is 5.1.4, here is the details:

> Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio

```
print(string.format("where id = %d", "1596856742980208710"))
```

output:

```
where id = 1596856742980208640
```

But when changing `%d` to `%s`:

```
print(string.format("where id = %s", "1596856742980208710"))
```

output:

```
where id = 1596856742980208710
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51665450/16835308) help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is a Lua "feature" called [coercion](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.2.1): Lua will coerce strings to numbers if a number is expected and vice versa. Lua 5.1 by default uses doubles as only number type, which may lead to a loss of precision when coercing large numbers.**

Consider your first example:

```lua
print(string.format("where id = %d", "1596856742980208710"))
```

`%d` obviously expects a number. The string `"1596856742980208710"` is thus coerced to a number; the code is equivalent to

```lua
print(string.format("where id = %d", tonumber"1596856742980208710"))
```

on newer Lua versions (5.3+), this would work just fine, since the number would be converted to a 64-bit signed integer:

```lua
$ lua
Lua 5.3.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2017 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> tonumber"1596856742980208710"
1596856742980208710
```

Lua 5.1 does however not have an integer type; it will convert the number to a 64-bit double:

```lua
$ lua5.1
Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> =("%d"):format(tonumber"1596856742980208710")
1596856742980208640
```

as you can see, the number has changed. This is because of double precision issues: The maximum safe integer that can be stored in a double is 2^53 - 1 (see e.g. JS's [`MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)). Your number significantly exceeds that: Compare `9.007199254741e+15` against `1596856742980208710`. This leads to a **loss of precision** in the less significant decimal places. When the number is then formatted using `%d`, you get the incorrect result.

Your second example:

```lua
print(string.format("where id = %s", "1596856742980208710"))
```

obviously works, since it treats `"1596856742980208710"` as a string and doesn't coerce it to a number in the first place. It is thus equivalent to a string concatenation `"where id = " .. "1596856742980208710"` no matter the Lua version (as `"1596856742980208710"` doesn't contain NULL bytes).